# Getting tables side by side with H4 tag on top of each table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I cannot get this to work for the life of me. I want to have both tables side by side on the same line and have the h4 tag over top of the right table it is suppose to be with. I can get the tables side by side without the h4 tags but i want the h4 tags. Also for these tables to be one on the left and one on the right. Sorry if this is a lot.

This is what I have so far.

```css
.table1,
#tableTitle1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.table2,
#tableTitle2 {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
.table1,
.table2 {
  height: 230px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!--First Table-->
<h4 id="tableTitle1">Graduates Status 2015</h4>
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Graduates</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5218</td>
    <td>Available for Employment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>936</td>
    <td>Future Education</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>158</td>
    <td>Not Seeking Employment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1866</td>
    <td>Unable to Contact</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--Second Table-->
<h4 id="tableTitle1">Graduates Employment Rates</h4>
<table class="table2">
  <tr>
    <th>Graduates</th>
    <th>Employment Rates (100%)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employment Related (Full-time)</td>
    <td>46.1%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employment Related (Part-time)</td>
    <td>8.3%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employment Unrelated (Full-time)</td>
    <td>19.8%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employment Unrelated (Part-time)</td>
    <td>16.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Not Employment</td>
    <td>19%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply add the title as table caption, here with an extra wrapper to keep them side-by-side, top aligned.

```css
.tablewrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#tableTitle1,
#tableTitle2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.table1,
.table2 {
  height: 230px;
  display: inline-table;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tablewrap">
  <!--First Table-->
  <table class="table1">
    <caption id="tableTitle1">
      Graduates Status 2015
    </caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Graduates</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5218</td>
      <td>Available for Employment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>936</td>
      <td>Future Education</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>158</td>
      <td>Not Seeking Employment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1866</td>
      <td>Unable to Contact</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!--Second Table-->
  <table class="table2">
    <caption id="tableTitle1">Graduates Employment Rates</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Graduates</th>
      <th>Employment Rates (100%)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Employment Related (Full-time)</td>
      <td>46.1%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Employment Related (Part-time)</td>
      <td>8.3%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Employment Unrelated (Full-time)</td>
      <td>19.8%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Employment Unrelated (Part-time)</td>
      <td>16.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Not Employment</td>
      <td>19%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the tables and H4s in a div, and float them:

```
//css
    .table-wrapper {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
    }

//html

    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <h4 id="tableTitle1">Graduates Status 2015</h4>
        <table class="table1">
         ...
        </table>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jrp1f2dg/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the html elements you want into `span`'s, and then apply `flex` properties to them with css. See the [codepen](http://codepen.io/dawsonbotsford/pen/jrJqPQ/).

html:

```
<!--First Table-->
<span class="flex-wrapper">
  <span class="flex-wrapper columns">
        <h1 id="tableTitle1">Graduates Status 2015</h4>
        <table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <th>Graduates</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5218</td>
                <td>Available for Employment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>936</td>
                <td>Future Education</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>158</td>
                <td>Not Seeking Employment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1866</td>
                <td>Unable to Contact</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </span>
<span class="flex-wrapper columns">
        <!--Second Table-->
        <h1 id="tableTitle1">Graduates Employment Rates</h4>
        <table class="table2">
            <tr>
                <th>Graduates</th>
                <th>Employment Rates (100%)</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employment Related (Full-time)</td>
                <td>46.1%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employment Related (Part-time)</td>
                <td>8.3%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employment Unrelated (Full-time)</td>
                <td>19.8%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employment Unrelated (Part-time)</td>
                <td>16.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Not Employment</td>
                <td>19%</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </span>
</span>
```

css:

```
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex
}

.columns {
  flex-direction: column
}

.table1,
#tableTitle1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table2,
#tableTitle2 {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table1,
.table2 {
  height: 230px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-spacing: 3px;
}
```

Here's what it will look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have display:inline-table.It just makes table element to behave inline
I guess we can make use of it here
check this [link][1]
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have typing mistake with second id, it could be `tableTitle2` instead `tableTitle1`.
Then wrap each table with its `<h4>` in `div` and apply `float` for them:

```
<div class="left">
  ..your markup..
</div>
<div class="right">
  ..your markup..
</div>
```

```
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/atb1xezm/)

If you want responsive tables, use percents for their widths:

```
div {
  width: 50%;
}
.table1,
.table2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/atb1xezm/1/)

I commented all unused css